# Sample each group after pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, random, group-by

How do I sample each group after groupby operation?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                   'b': [1,1,1,0,0,0,0]})

grouped = df.groupby('b')
```

Given the above setup, I want to sample from each group, e.g., I want 30% of each group.

Comment: from pandas 1.1, you can just do `df.groupby('b').sample()`. [Relevant docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html)

Comment: In case you are looking for sampling different amount per group:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59437554/8502312

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Apply a lambda and call [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sample.html) with param `frac`:

```
In [2]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                   'b': [1,1,1,0,0,0,0]})
​
grouped = df.groupby('b')
grouped.apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.3))

Out[2]:
     a  b
b        
0 6  7  0
1 2  3  1
```

Answer (score 53):

### pandas >= 1.1: [`GroupBy.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html)

This works like magic:

```
# np.random.seed(0)
df.groupby('b').sample(frac=.3) 

   a  b
5  6  0
0  1  1
```

---

### pandas <= 1.0.X

You can use [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html). You do not need to use a lambda; `apply` accepts keyword arguments:

```
df.groupby('b', group_keys=False).apply(pd.DataFrame.sample, frac=.3)

   a  b
5  6  0
0  1  1
```

Comment: ```df.sample(frac=1).groupby('b').head(2)```
This one is not the same. Sample take samples uniformly, this one first first one. The usage of them depend on task, but the head one depend on sorting order, when sample does not.