# How to make sure certain items is added when data sampling in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

> My Pandas Dataframe looks like this

```
|id| name | condition | category | brand_name | price
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1|Shirt |   3       | Men Clot | Easy       | 250
```

> **More information about dataset:**    The dataset `brand_name` column has 150 unique brand name and `category` column has over 89 unique categories.
>   The dataset has over 1000k~ rows.

I need only 10k rows from the data set. So I want to use pandas built-in function `pandas.DataFrame.sample`. But it sample data randomly. But I want to make sure that ***my 10k data points (a subset of the main dataset) contain all the unique brand name and category***. Not only that I also need 10 rows with each unique brand name.

> **Tried Solutions:** I tried pandas `groupby` function. But It only uses unique values. But I need not only unique values but also 10 rows with each value. I tried to search all over the StackOverflow but doesn't find my solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390406/pandas-sample-each-group-after-groupby - in groupby mention brand and category `groupby(['brand','category'])` then apply sample

Comment: I see, misunderstood the question.