# Removing random rows from a data frame until count is equal some criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with data that I feed to a ML library in python. The data I have is categorized into 5 different tasks, t1,t2,t3,t4,t5. The data I have right now for every task is uneven, to simplify things here is an example.

```
task, someValue
t1,   XXX
t1,   XXX
t1,   XXX
t1,   XXX
t2,   XXX
t2,   XXX
```

In the case above, I want to remove random rows with the task label of "t1" until there is an equal amount of "t1" as there is "t2"
So after the code is run, it should look like this:

```
task, someValue
t1,   XXX
t1,   XXX
t2,   XXX
t2,   XXX
```

What is the most clean way to do this? I could of course just do for loops and if conditions and use random numbers and count the occurances for each iteration, but that solution would not be very elegant. Surely there must be a way using functions of dataframe? So far, this is what I got:

```
def equalize_rows(df):
    t = df['task'].value_counts()
    mininmum_occurance = min(t)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the smallest number of tasks in your dataFrame, and then use `groupby` + `head` to get the top N rows per task.

```
v = df['task'].value_counts().min()
df = df.groupby('task', as_index=False).head(v)
```

```
df
  task someValue
0   t1       XXX
1   t1       XXX
4   t2       XXX
5   t2       XXX
```

Comment: Clear and simple solution, thanks! But sadly it is not random but it should still work for me! :)

Comment: @Fupp2 You can first do `df = df.sample(frac=1)` and then `df.groupby('task', sort=False, as_index=False).head(v)` if you want random rows

Comment: @Fupp2 Sorry, you need to assign it back: `df = df.groupby('task', sort=False, as_index=False).head(v)`

Comment: Ah, alright, thanks! 
However, I'm now thinking random maybe is not the best choice. Is it possible to do this but start removing every second row and then remove the head or something after that? I'm afraid the data will become skewed

Comment: @Fupp2 I recommend taking a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390406/pandas-sample-each-group-after-groupby it isn't exactly what you asked but may help