# How do you get the top n rows of each group in a python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, apply

How do you get the top n rows of each group in a python pandas dataframe?

Comment: Solution tailored from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59437334/how-to-sample-different-number-of-rows-from-each-group-in-dataframe) about sampling n random rows from each group

Comment: Hi @BigBen, thank you for the advice! I am new to posting and practicing posting a question I had along with a solution I found

Comment: Forgive my novice knowledge on the matter. Thanks, @BigBen!

Comment: It may help you to see [ask] and also (re)take the [tour].

Comment: A sample dataframe and the corresponding expected output would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
n=10
top10each = df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda group: group.head(n)).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).