# How to get a sample dataset from large datafram while keeping the proportion of categorical variables in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large DataFrame with 2 million observations. For my further analysis, I intend to use a relatively smaller sample (around 15-20% of the original DataFrame) drawn from the original DataFrame. While sampling, I also intend to keep the proportion of categorical values present in one of the columns intact.

For eg: if one column has 5 categories as its values: red(20% of total observations), green(10%), blue(15%), white(25%), yellow(30%); I would like the column in the sample dataset to also show the same proportion of different categories.

Please assist!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sample each group after pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390406/sample-each-group-after-pandas-groupby)

Comment: I tried this but it turns the categories into something similar to an index and therefore aren't practically a column anymore. How can I, say, ungroup it back!?

Comment: You can try adding the argument as_index = False in the groupby()

Comment: that works perfectly! Thanks!